# How can I make a large grid of buttons (24x20 or similar) in vb.net using winforms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, button, user-controls

I'm making a seat booking system in vb.net (WinForms) and I need the user to be able to select the seat they wish to use and for it to change colour (so they can tell that it selected).

I began to try using buttons, but 480 buttons seriously slowed down the load time for the form. I then tried a data grid view with buttons in the rows/columns, but couldnt make that work properly.

My question is, how can I do this?

Would it be worth trying to use 480 picture boxes and change their background colour? Or would that just slow the form down the same way as 480 buttons?

Comment: You need to make it clear that it's a WinForms app.

Comment: Maybe a DataGrid of buttons? This would also solve binding your datasource backend holding information about free/reserved status I guess.

Comment: I tried that but I couldn't make it work nicely...

Comment: Hi John Try by creating controls Dynamically.

Comment: Is it possible to let the user select a section first? Like: section A, then seat assignment? It would prevent the user being assailed with a giant grid.  It doesn't answer "how I present 24x20 grid in winforms", but it might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For efficiency sake, you don't really want to just create a ton of controls like that.  It would be better to make a single custom control that draws all the seats on it's own single drawing surface.  Here's a very simple example:

```
Public Class SeatingPlan
    Public Class Seat
        Public Rectangle As Rectangle
        Public Selected As Boolean
        Public Id As String

        Public Sub New(ByVal seatId As String, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal width As Integer, ByVal height As Integer)
            Id = seatId
            Rectangle = New Rectangle(x, y, width, height)
        End Sub
    End Class


    Public ReadOnly Property Seats() As List(Of Seat)
        Get
            Return _seats
        End Get
    End Property
    Private _seats As List(Of Seat) = New List(Of Seat)()


    Public Event SelectedSeatsChanged()


    Private Sub SeatingPlan_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
        For Each seat As Seat In _seats
            If seat.Rectangle.Contains(e.Location) Then
                seat.Selected = Not seat.Selected
                RaiseEvent SelectedSeatsChanged()
                Exit For
            End If
        Next
        Invalidate()
    End Sub


    Private Sub SeatingPlan_Paint(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        For Each seat As Seat In _seats
            Dim seatBackColor As Color = BackColor
            Dim textColor As Color = ForeColor
            If seat.Selected Then
                seatBackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.Highlight)
                textColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.HighlightText)
            End If
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(New SolidBrush(seatBackColor), seat.Rectangle)
            e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(New Pen(ForeColor), seat.Rectangle)
            Dim textSize As SizeF = e.Graphics.MeasureString(seat.Id, Me.Font, seat.Rectangle.Width)
            e.Graphics.DrawString(seat.Id, Font, New SolidBrush(textColor), seat.Rectangle.X + ((seat.Rectangle.Width - textSize.Width) / 2), seat.Rectangle.Y + ((seat.Rectangle.Height - textSize.Height) / 2))
        Next
    End Sub


    Public Function GetSelectedSeatIds() As List(Of String)
        Dim ids As List(Of String) = New List(Of String)()
        For Each seat As Seat In _seats
            If seat.Selected Then
                ids.Add(seat.Id)
            End If
        Next
        Return ids
    End Function


    Public Sub SetSelectedSeatIds(ids As List(Of String))
        For Each seat As Seat In _seats
            seat.Selected = ids.Contains(seat.Id)
        Next
        RaiseEvent SelectedSeatsChanged()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Then, in your form, put some code like this to create the locations of the seats:

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    SeatingPlan1.Seats.Add(New SeatingPlan.Seat("1A", 3, 3, 20, 20))
    SeatingPlan1.Seats.Add(New SeatingPlan.Seat("2A", 26, 3, 20, 20))
    SeatingPlan1.Seats.Add(New SeatingPlan.Seat("1B", 3, 26, 20, 20))
    SeatingPlan1.Seats.Add(New SeatingPlan.Seat("2B", 26, 26, 20, 20))
End Sub


Private Sub SeatingPlan1_SelectedSeatsChanged() Handles SeatingPlan1.SelectedSeatsChanged
    For Each seatId As String In SeatingPlan1.GetSelectedSeatIds
        'Do something
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Right click on your project and select Add > User Control from the context menu.  Call it SeatingPlan (or whatever you like), then copy and paste this code into the code for the user control.  Then build the project.  Then go to the designer for your form and the SeatingPlan control should show at the top of your tool box.

Comment: Thanks for this mate, I think this will probably work for me!

Comment: How would I add an index so that I can record what seats are selected?

Comment: What I would do is make a public property for the list of seats.  It should probably raise an event too when a seat is selected or de-selected so the form can be notified when it changes.  Also, the list of seats should probably be populated by the form rather than by the control's Load event.  That way the control could be reused for different seating arrangements.

Comment: How would I do that sorry :/ I know how to define a property and I figured out how to get the index of the clicked on box, but I can't work out how to make it output properly... Ideally I would like a selecteditems property like a listbox...

Comment: Argh! I'm sure its so simple, but I can't figure out how to get the indices that are selected!

Comment: I figured it out! Thankyou so much mate :)

Comment: Sorry to keep bothering you, but how could I get a 2D reference of a particular rectangle from the index? I can't work out how!

Comment: I just updated my example to include keeping track of seat ID's which is probably what you want more than the indices, anyway.  I added printing the ID on the seat boxes, and a method that returns the ID's of all the selected seats.  Hopefully that meets what you need or gives you more ideas on how to do what you need.

Comment: I'm assuming by 2D reference, you mean row and column, right?  Hopefully my ID thing meets what you need, but if not, instead of an ID as string, change that to a SeatPosition as Point.  Then, when you add the seats, it will require you to specify the seat position of each seat as you add them.

Comment: Yeah your ID thing was exactly what i meant it worked amazingly! I'm able to edit everything to make it exactly how I want it now so thankyou!

Comment: Yeah, I think something like that would be better for a seating chart where every seat may not always fit neatly into a forced row and column scheme.

Comment: Hi mate hope your still there! What would I need to add to have a property where I could input the ID's of boxes to already be selected?

Comment: I added a SetSelectedSeatIds method that should work for you.

Comment: Hi mate, it seems that getSelectedSeatIds seems to get the same ID multiple times if the control is used over and over again. How can I avoid this?

Comment: Perhaps you are adding all the seats into the control multiple times and they are overlapped so you don't notice them.  Check the count on the control's Seats property.

Comment: Hi mate, that was in fact the problem! But I fixed it. Another question though - how can I make it repaint only the selected chair when it is selected?

Comment: If your concern is simply that you see the control flicker while it draws, you can simply turn on double buffering.  To do that, open the designer for the SeatingPlan control and change the value for the DoubleBuffered property to True.  If, however, your concern is that it takes too long to draw all the seats every time, you would need to implement double buffering yourself so you can redraw only the seat that changed.  Manually implementing your own double buffering is not difficult, but if all you're concerned about is the flickering, setting that property is much easier.

Comment: Be careful not to stray into extended discussions that don't relate to the topic at hand. Use chat if necessary.

Comment: Thanks SteveDog! Sorry BoltClock - I would use chat but I don't have enough rep yet! When I have some spare time ill start answering questions and improve it!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int index;
            Button[] b=new Button[500];
            for(int i=0;i<24;i++)
            for(int j=0;j<20;j++)
            {
                index = (20 * i) + j;
                b[index]=new Button();
                b[index].Text=index.ToString();
                b[index].Location=new Point(j*80,i*30);
                panel1.Controls.Add(b[index]);
                b[index].Click += new EventHandler(ButtonLeft_Click);    
             }

            }

        private void ButtonLeft_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Button b = (Button)sender;
            if (b.BackColor == Color.Black)
                b.BackColor = Color.White;
            else
                b.BackColor = Color.Black;

              //DB Commands here    
        }
```

Comment: That works pretty well, but I was hoping to have the 24 width ways with an aisle after 12 seats and an aisle after 10 seats longways.

Comment: Also, it appears that although the rows go 1 to 20, the next row starts with 10?

Comment: How many downvotes would I get if I posted VB.NET code on a C# question that didn't have a VB tag?