# How To add 2 or more "USERCONTROL" into a panel at one time

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

Is there any way you add usercontrol to a panel at a time...i am using this code..

```
    Dim Project as New Usercontrol
    Panel1.Controls.Add(Project)
    Panel1.Controls.Add(Project)
```

And it adds only 1 user control and edited text in that user controls instead of creating a new usercontrol...

Any answers..

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are adding the same instance of the user control twice.  That won't work.  You would need to create two separate instances of the control and then add both of them to the panel:

```
Dim Project1 as New Usercontrol
Panel1.Controls.Add(Project1)
Dim Project2 as New Usercontrol
Panel1.Controls.Add(Project2)
```

Comment: @SteveDos is there any other way...because i got lot of manual usercontrols...maybe 1 or2 or 6 or 10 etc...

Comment: If you have 10 references to the same instance of the control, that's still only 1 actual instance of the control.  If you want your control to show multiple times on the screen, you have to create multiple instances of it.  There is no other way.  If you are concerned about having too many instances of the same control, you may need to reconsider your design. You could only show one control at a time but have forward and back buttons or a list of rows to change which data the control is displaying. Or, you could design a single user control that shows all the sub controls as a single control.

Comment: I don't know if this is related, or not, to your concern about too many controls, but check out my answer to this other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481418/how-can-i-make-a-large-grid-of-buttons-24x20-or-similar-in-vb-net-using-winfor