# Creating chess graphics in Visual Basic

Tags: vb.net, chess

I am creating a multiplayer chess game in Visual Basic.Net and I need to create tiles for the game. 
Earlier, I used buttons for the tiles, but then I realized that not only did they look ugly, but the coding part also became a problem. Also, the images of the chess pieces didn't properly fit on the buttons and they became distorted. Also, shifting the image to a different button every time a move was played also became very inefficient. 
So, in view of these difficulties, I want to build a proper board, but I have no idea where to start from or what controls to use for the design. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know a lot about c++ but I am using VB because I want to get more familiar with it. And the graphics part is also important. The icons aren't fitting properly though I found a way out now. And secondly, I am not going to make a computer versus human chess engine. For now, its only human versus human so its a bit easier. After this is over I will move on to computer versus human

Comment: For a really simple example of using GDI to draw your own surface, check out my answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10481418/how-can-i-make-a-large-grid-of-buttons-24x20-or-similar-in-vb-net-using-winfor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Chess Program using VB.NET : http://www.vbdotnetheaven.com/UploadFile/kaushalgol/ChessProgramInVB11142005235115PM/ChessProgramInVB.aspx

This was coded in VB6 : http://freesourcecodevisualbasic.blogspot.se/2011/07/source-code-2-player-chess.html

Answer (score 1):

You don't wany to use controls for the pieces you should just draw the image directly onto your form. You then have full control of exactly where everything is drawn.

You need to hold some form of data structure that 'remembers' where all your pieces are.

Have a look at [this link to GDI+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa289159%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to help get you started

Comment: I got it. What I did was, I created 64 picture boxes and set their back colors as either black or white and then the image of the picture box was the image icon of the pieces. Now, whenever I want to move a piece I will simply move the image.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest it might be too complicated for a school project. Maybe if you reduce the scope - try for just human vs human.

Anyway,

[The chess programming wiki](http://chessprogramming.wikispaces.com/)

[Bruce Moreland's old page on MinMax and other adversarial search algorithms](http://web.archive.org/web/20071213180053/www.seanet.com/~brucemo/topics/topics.htm)

I have more links but i cant post any links anymore. It's limited to 2 links only. Im sorry.